# Generating Aging Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, report

I need to generate an aging report using the below sample data from **tblAccount**.

```
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
| Loan ID | Account  |     Name      | Amortization Date | Amortized Principal | Paid Amount | Date Paid | Balance |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
|       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON | 3/9/2020          |             3823.53 |     3823.53 | 3/9/2020  |       0 |
|       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON | 4/9/2020          |             3823.53 |         500 | 3/9/2020  | 3323.53 |
|       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON | 5/9/2020          |             3823.53 |           0 | NULL      | 3823.53 |
+---------+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------------+-------------+-----------+---------+
```

Zero (0) paid amount and *NULL* Date Paid means that the amortized principal is not yet paid. Below is my desired output for specific Aging dates.

**Aging A - Aging on March 12** Payment has been made on March 12 for March 9 schedule

```
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-----
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
| Loan ID | Account  |     Name      |    Due     |  Payment   | Balance | Current |  30   |  60   |  90   | 120 and Above |
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
|       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON |  3,823.53  |  3,823.53  |       0 |    -    |  -    |  -    |  -    |          -    |
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-------+---------------+
```

**Aging B - May 10** 500.00 payment has been made on April 9 for April 9 schedule

```
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
| Loan ID | Account  |     Name      |    Due     | Payment  |  Balance   |  Current   |  30   |  60   |  90   |  120 and Above  |
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
|       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON |  3,823.53  |  500.00  |  3,323.53  |  3,323.53  |  -    |  -    |  -    |            -    |
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+----------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-----------------+
```

**Aging C - June 10** There is remaining balance for April 9 schedule and no payment made for May 9

schdeule

```
    +---------+----------+---------------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------+
| Loan ID | Account  |     Name      |    Due     | Payment |  Balance   |  Current  |     30     |     60     |  90   |  120 and Above  |
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------+
|       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON |  7,147.06  |     500 |  7,147.06  |      -    |  3,823.53  |  3,323.53  |  -    |            -    |
+---------+----------+---------------+------------+---------+------------+-----------+------------+------------+-------+-----------------+
```

I have looked and tried suggested solutions here, made tweeks, but it seems that it does not fit to what I wanted to produce.

Currently, I have this kind of Stored Procedure:

```
INSERT INTO @Aging (
Loan, ID, Account, Name, AmortizationSchedule,  AmortizedPrincipal, PaidAmount, DatePaid, Balance)
SELECT Loan, ID, Account, Name, AmortizationSchedule,   AmortizedPrincipal, PaidAmount, DatePaid, Balance
 FROM tblAccount

Select DISTINCT Loan, ID, Account, Name, AmortizationSchedule,  AmortizedPrincipal, PaidAmount, DatePaid, Balance
    (case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf  )) < 1 then balance else 0 end) as [Current],
    (case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf  )) between 1 and 30 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo30],
    (case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf  )) between 31 and 60 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo60],
    (case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf  )) between 61 and 90 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo90],
    (case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf  )) between 91 and 120 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo120],
    (case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf  )) > 120 then balance else 0 end) as [Over120]
from @Aging where balance<>0.00  
order by Account
```

But it gives the following result,

```
 +---------+----------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------+----+-----------------+
    | Loan ID | Account  |     Name      |     Due     |  Payment   |   Balance   |  Current  |  30   |     60      | 90 |  120 and Above  |
    +---------+----------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------+----+-----------------+
    |       2 | A0007787 | JIMMY NEUTRON |  90,000.00  |  8,647.06  |  14,294.12  |      -    |  -    |  14,294.12  |  0 |               0 |
    +---------+----------+---------------+-------------+------------+-------------+-----------+-------+-------------+----+-----------------+
```

It seems that it duplicate the value of due, payment and balance on the number of amortization schedule which is three (March, April, May)

Hoping for a positive response. TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query gives the correct results once `group by` and `sum` used. Am I missing something?

```
Select DISTINCT [Loan ID], Account, [Name]
,sum(AmortizedPrincipal) Due, sum(PaidAmount) Payment, sum(Balance) Balance,
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf)) < 1 then balance else 0 end) as [Current],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf)) between 1 and 30 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo30],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf)) between 31 and 60 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo60],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf)) between 61 and 90 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo90],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf)) between 91 and 120 then balance else 0 end) as [DueTo120],
    sum(case when DATEDIFF(day,convert(date,AmortizationSchedule),convert(date,@DateAsOf)) > 120 then balance else 0 end) as [Over120]
from @Aging where balance<>0.00  
GROUP BY [Loan ID], Account, [Name]
order by Account
```

Please check the db<>fiddle **[here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=95a1314cd63ba97d7d6676645293e8cf)**.